# Does Roller Blading count as a step in all cases where number of steps matter (like for hatching an egg)?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Running, the Bicycle and walking all use the classic 'grid' movement (even the new diagonal movement is still based on the grid).

The Rollerblades do not follow the grid. You are in a free-moving state instead. Do they still count towards steps?

Comment: I imagine it would, since when you hop off of your blades you move to whatever grid location you were mostly in. That being said, I haven't actually tried to hatch any eggs yet so I cannot confirm.

Comment: I had forgotten that I could test it by trying to rollerblade the last few steps. So yes they do count.

Comment: @Reafexus Then, please, do post an actual answer yourself. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Rollerskating does count. I was able to rollerskate the last few hundred steps of my eggs life-cycle and they still hatched.